# $\sum f(n)$ when $f>0$ verifies: $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}, n>N \implies \forall p\geq n, f(n+p)\leq f(n)e^{-pA}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{+*}$ and $N>0; A\in\mathbb{R}^{*+}$.

We suposse $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}, n>N \implies \forall p\geq n, f(n+p)\leq f(n)e^{-pA}$

Show that $\sum f(n)$ converges.

Comment: What is $A$????

Comment: A positive real. Edited to be clearer.

Comment: Do you mean $p \ge n$ or $p \ge 0$?

Comment: I really mean $p\geq n$

Comment: Check tes MP sur JVC ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trivial.

Let $n=N+1$, then for all $p\geq N+1$, $f(N+p)\leq f(N)e^{-pA}$.

This implies the series $\sum_{p\geq N+1}f(N+p)$ converges, hence $\sum_{p\geq 2N+1}f(p)$ converges, hence $\sum_{p\geq 1}f(p)$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

I think an integral test does it.

$$\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} f(n) \leq f(1) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(1)e^{-nA} \leq f(1) + f(1)\int_0^\infty e^{-Ax} dx$$

Where in my first step, I'm using that

$f(2) = f(1+1) \leq f(1)e^{-A}$

$f(3) = f(1+2) \leq f(1)e^{-2A}$

And so on ...

Answer (score 1):

$\forall n \in\mathbb{N}, n>N \implies \forall p\geq n, f(n+p)\leq f(n)e^{-pA}
$

Putting $n = N+1$,
this becomes

$\forall p\geq N+1, f(N+1+p)\leq f(N+1)e^{-pA}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{p \ge N+1} f(N+1+p)
& \le \sum_{p \ge N+1} f(N+1)e^{-pA}\\
&=f(N+1) \sum_{p \ge N+1} e^{-pA}\\
&=f(N+1)e^{-(N+1)A}\dfrac1{1-e^{-A}}\\
\end{array}
$

so it converges.

Comment: I really meant $p\geq n$; so you cannot suppose that.

Comment: As long as some tail converges, the whole sum converges.